# How to write bold all of the text?

Tags: bold

I know how to write a paragraph with bold(with \textbf{}). But if I want write all of my pages with bold, how can I do it? A way is using \textbf{} at the beginning of my paragraphs. But I know there is an easy way to do it. (in the site I couldn't find the solution). Can anyone help me.(Thank you very much)

Comment: You could say `\bfseries`, which will stay in force until countermanded.  You could also consider choosing a font that is more bold by default.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you. It works. but it doesn't countermand. In fact I write: "\bfseries{ some text} again some text". And all of the text will be bold. How can stop the bold?

Comment: I found out. I must write: "{\bfseries   some text } again some text ".  Thank you.

Comment: `\bfseries` to switch to bold face weight, `\mdseries` to switch back to medium weight (normal).

Comment: @Cicada  Thank you. Your command works(although \mdseries is not in  the "memory" of my TexStudio ). Is my way wrong or does my way have a problem?

Comment: The `{}` restrict the scope of the commands to within the {}. So it depends on how much you want to type. Also, `\textbf` is effectively defined as `\newcommand{\textbf}[1]{{\bfseries #1}}` anyway, so it is all the same in the end.

Comment: Perhaps it could be said, `\textbf{...}` and `{\bfseries ...}` are for shorter texts, and `\bfseries...\mdseries` for (very) long texts. In any case, you have the choice. Experiment: Ah! `\textbf{xxxx\par xxxx}` errors out, `\textbf{xxxx\newpage xxxx}` works. Interesting.

Comment: IIRC, you can also stop \bfseries with \normalfont.

Comment: And you can also give up your idea. The more text you highlight, less highlighted and more annoying will be. Highlight only a  few words aside from the tiles (ideally none).